# How to fix error on android webview

Tags: android, xml, webview

So here are my codes :

```
public class AboutActivity extends Activity{

    WebView aboutwebview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_profile_settings);

        aboutwebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.aboutwebview);
        aboutwebview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        aboutwebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pickld.html");
    } 

}
```

and here is the `xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="#7fad33"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Our Team"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/aboutwebview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and im pretty sure that the `html` file is on the **assets** folder, i also put a permission on the manifest file, but when i run the application, im getting a force close error its says that the problem is on this line :

```
aboutwebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pickld.html");
```

im wondering what could be the problem.

here's the logcat error :

[image]

Comment: What is the problem? Post error log

Comment: Please post logcat error.

Comment: Looks like `webview` is null. is that the xml in which you have webview?

Comment: Are you sure that you posted edit_profile_settings.xml code? check if you are using correct layout. you are getting NPE.

Comment: pickld.html file is correct?

Comment: Are you sure `aboutwebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pickld.html");` is the line on line 21?

Comment: `aboutwebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pickld.html")` line is correct. this can't cause NPE. Did you posted all code of onCreate()?

Comment: Oh yeah thank you for helping me :) 

you might wanna put your answers guys so i can accept it. :D

Comment: @GreenFox which one was it setting wrong xml to activity

Comment: @Raghunandan the layout that i used is a different layout thank :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this line causes NPE

```
 aboutwebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pickld.html");
```

means your `aboutwebview` is null. Either you refer to the wrong id or you set the wrong layout to your activity  with `setContentView(R.layout.edit_profile_settings);`. Make sure you do that right to avod NPE.